# Cant iterate through an associative array using jquery.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

Well, I have used `jquery.each` before but today seems to be my bad day as whatever I am doing is going way wrong. I used the following to get the values from the array but I get

> TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a

**JS**

```
var updateBoard = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "engine/main.php",
            data: {code: 2},
            success: function(response) {
                $.each(response, function(i, val) {
                    console.log(i);
                });
                setTimeout(updateBoard, 2500);
            }
        });
    };
    updateBoard();
```

**RESPONSE IN MY SUCCESS FUNCTION**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cell] => a2
            [sign] => &#9711;
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cell] => b2
            [sign] => &#9711;
        )

)
```

Comment: Your response (as you pasted it) does not look like a javascript array

Comment: its from a PHP script.

Comment: I guess you should serialize it into some JSON object/array if you want to process it with javascript.

Comment: Actually I am sending the decoded json array(which I pasted) to the client side. Cant we just iterate over the array to get the values?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not valid JSON...

Comment: Its just an assoc array. Cant we do on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133744/discussion-between-dario-and-ayan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
$(obj).each(function(i, val) {
  console.log(val.cell);
  console.log(val.sign);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

each its work only on jQuery element but response isn't bind with jQuery selector so just use javascript loop like this

you can use map function of es6 or foreachfunction if your response is an array

try :

```
response.map(function(obj){
  console.log(obj)
})
```

or

```
response.forEach(function(obj){
  console.log(obj)
})
```

source of MDN

foreach

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I get this `TypeError: response.forEach is not a function`